# MongoDB select all embedded documents by criteria without root

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way to select all embedded documents from collection´s field (array) without the root document? For example given this collection

```
{ "_id" : 1, "cars" : [{"brand": "audi", "color": "red"}, {"brand": "audi", "color": "yellow"}]}
{ "_id" : 2, "cars" : [{"brand": "audi", "color": "blue"}, {"brand": "seat"}]}
```

I would like to select all cars with the brand `audi` with the following output

```
{"brand": "audi", "color": "red"}
{"brand": "audi", "color": "blue"}
{"brand": "audi", "color": "yellow"}
```

It does not seems to be possible with just `db.collection.find()` with `projection` because its matching criteria is always related to the root document.

Comment: @SagarReddy This will select all root objects that have at least one car that matches brand = 'audi'. But for example that one 'seat' car in second document will be wrongly included.

Comment: `db.collection.find({'cars.brand': 'audi'}, {'cars.$': 1})`

Comment: @Styvane This will only get the first matching record. I think OP needs all the matching entries.

Comment: @Styvane This is what SagarReddy wrote but won´t match all entries.

Comment: What is your mongod version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use an aggregation that will :

- `$unwind` you cars array
- `$match` only audi `brand`
- `$group` by brand & color to remove duplicates
- `$project` to reorganize output

Query is :

```
db.cars.aggregate([{
    $unwind: '$cars'
}, {
    $match: {
        'cars.brand': 'audi'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        '_id': { 'brand': '$cars.brand', 'color': '$cars.color' }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        'brand': '$_id.brand',
        'color': '$_id.color'
    }
}])
```

Comment: Can you nest $unwind for nested embedded documents?

Comment: You can unwind your nested array after the root one : `db.cars.aggregate([{     $unwind: '$topArray' }, {     $unwind: '$topArray.cars' }])`